# Adding Subtotals with No Unique Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I made a query that adds the adds the line amount of each commodity into a subtotal. However, due to lack of unique columns, I am using the "Created_Date" column in my loop to tell the procedure which numbers to add (or not add) and move on. This worked for the most part until I realized we had machines to do data entry and not people so the "Created_Date" could be the same down the second, though it rarely happens.

How would you change my loop to add the "line amount" into the subtotal even with the same "Create_Date" if the Commodity is the same without breaking the whole thing? Thanks.

An example of what is not adding (note the Create_Date):

[image]

My code/query:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT DISTINCT
           ISNULL(T.PRODUCT_ID, 'NULL') AS [Commodity], 
           ISNULL(T.PO_NO, 'NULL') AS [PO NO],
           ISNULL(T.LINE_NO, 'NULL') AS [LINE NO],
           QUOTENAME(T.DESCRIPTION, '"') AS [PO Line Description],
           QUOTENAME(C.DESCRIPTION, '"') AS [Commodity Description],
           ISNULL(T.FY, 'NULL') AS [Fiscal Year],
           PH.Vendor_ID AS [Vendor ID],
           QUOTENAME (V.Vendor_Name, '"') AS [Vendor Name],
           T.QUANTITY,
           T.UNIT_COST,
           T.QUANTITY*T.UNIT_COST AS [Line Amount],
           PH.Created_Date,
           (Select CAST(0.00 as numeric(10,2))) AS Sub_Total_Cost
    INTO ##TmpPOReport             
    FROM       dbo.DBVW_FI_REQ_PO_ITEMS T
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_VENDOR FV ON T.INST_ID=FV.INST_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_REQ_PO_HEADER PH ON T.PO_NO=PH.PO_NO
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_VENDOR V ON PH.VENDOR_ID=V.VENDOR_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.FI_COMMODITY C ON T.PRODUCT_ID=C.FI_COMMODITY_CODE 

    WHERE      T.INST_ID = 'SC00' AND
               T.FY = '2015' AND
               V.VENDOR_TYPE = 'V' AND 
               T.PO_NO IS NOT NULL AND
               (T.PRODUCT_ID <> '' AND T.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL)
               AND T.QUANTITY*T.UNIT_COST BETWEEN '1000' AND '20000'
    Order By Commodity

    DECLARE @PID varchar(15)=00,
            @QUANTITY int,
            @UNIT_COST numeric(10,2),
            @PrevID varchar(15),
            @CreateDate datetime,
            @PrevDate datetime = getdate(),
            @RowAmount numeric(10,2),
            @SubTotal numeric(10,2) = 0.00

    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF; 

    WHILE EXISTS(Select TOP 1 * FROM ##TmpPOReport WHERE Sub_Total_Cost = 0.00)
    BEGIN
        SET @RowAmount = (Select TOP 1 (QUANTITY * UNIT_COST) FROM ##TmpPOReport WHERE Sub_Total_Cost = 0.00)

        SELECT TOP 1 @PID = Commodity, @CreateDate = Created_Date FROM ##TmpPOReport WHERE Sub_Total_Cost = 0.00
        IF(@PID = @PrevID)AND(@CreateDate <> @PrevDate)
            BEGIN
            SET @SubTotal += @RowAmount;
            UPDATE T SET Sub_Total_Cost = @SubTotal FROM ##TmpPOReport T WHERE T.Commodity = @PID AND T.Created_Date = @CreateDate
            SET @PrevID = @PID;
            SET @PrevDate = @CreateDate
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @SubTotal = @RowAmount;
            UPDATE T SET Sub_Total_Cost = @SubTotal FROM ##TmpPOReport T WHERE T.Commodity = @PID AND T.Created_Date = @CreateDate
            SET @PrevID = @PID;
            SET @PrevDate = @CreateDate
        END

    END

    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;  
    SELECT * FROM ##TmpPOReport
    WHERE [Line Amount] BETWEEN '1000' AND '20000'
    DROP TABLE ##TmpPOReport
END
```

Thanks again guys! Much appreciated.

Comment: Please post all relevant information in your question, rather than in links to external sites.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You may find [this site](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) helpful to see how you can make your problem easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a unique column in your temporary table by using the [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [Commodity], [PO NO], [LINE NO]) RowID,
    ...
INTO ##TmpPOReport 
from ...
```

Use the new RowID column instead of created date to differentiate specific PO Lines.

I didn't notice that you were using `Distinct`.  Adding a `row_number` to the select will nullify the `Distinct` because each row number returned will be unique.  You will have to use a group by instead to ensure that distinct rows will be returned.  So add to the end of the select:

```
GROUP BY
    T.PRODUCT_ID,
    T.PO_NO,
    T.LINE_NO,
    T.DESCRIPTION,
    C.DESCRIPTION,
    T.FY,
    PH.Vendor_ID,
    V.Vendor_Name,
    T.QUANTITY,
    T.UNIT_COST,
    PH.Created_Date
```

Comment: When I put that in, it seems to give me a lot of duplicates. I think it's because of the Select Distinct counting all the rows with RowID as different when the same rows were originally filtered by the Distinct. However, when I put that select ROW_NUMBER() clause between (), it just makes all the row numbers as "1".